# Класс Java через интент не находит класс на Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

В процессе рефакторинга переписывал некоторые классы с Java на Котлин и столкнулся с одной интересной проблемой: при попытке запустить класс через intent (из Java) - появилась ошибка

```
    error: cannot find symbol
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChangeDataSendlerActivity.class);
                                         ^
  symbol:   class ChangeDataSendlerActivity
  location: class SendToMolActivity
```

С чем она может быть связана и как ее поправить?
Вызов происходит так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChangeDataSendlerActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

P.S. Перейти в класс могу, в самом классе данные строчки не подчеркнуты и ошибок не имеют, пакеты сходятся (они в одной папке лежат), просто класс ChagneDataSendlerActivity был переписан с Java на Котлин

**UPD:** добавляю импорты

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;

import com.example.testingodata.BroadcastReceivers.ConnectivityChangedBroadcastReceiver;
import com.example.testingodata.BroadcastReceivers.SyncInBroadcastReceiver;
import com.example.testingodata.Entities.EntityBlockReceivingList;
import com.example.testingodata.Helpers.MarkupHelper;
import com.zebra.rfid.api3.RFIDReader;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
```

Манифест:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ChangeDataSendlerActivity"
            android:label="@string/send_mol"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"/>
```

Добавил импорт класса и появилась новая ошибка:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.testingodata.ChangeDataSendlerActivity;
                               ^
  symbol:   class ChangeDataSendlerActivity
  location: package com.example.testingodata
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, может дело в  манифесте?)

Comment: покажите пожалуйста импорта в вашем классе

Comment: Текст ошибки некорректный, какой именно символ не может быть найден?

Comment: @TonyLead нет, манифест корректный, импорт добавлю, но по-моему не в нем проблема

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja не может найти класс ChangeDataSendActivity (прикреплю скрин)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja подкорректировал ошибку

Comment: Судя по ошибке - у вас не с Intent, кажется, проблема. Покажите где и зачем у вас такой код: `ChangeDataSendlerActivity.show(this);`?

Comment: У вас ошибка компиляции, а вы нам все пишете "при попытке запустить" и "Вызов происходит так", т.е. об ошибке исполнения. Приведите только тот код, где ошибка, без ваших (неверных) предположений об ее источнике.

Comment: И не класс ChangeDataSendActivity не может найти, а переменную ChangeDataSendlerActivity в классе SendToMolActivity

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пытался немного по другому типу запустить другую активность

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja сорян за тупость, другой вариант просто пробовал. Обновил ошибку

Comment: Тут тогда просто импорта не хватает.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja разве? Добавил импорт класса, в итоге он выделен "серым" и та же ошибка

Comment: Компилятор вам говорит что нет в том пакете такого класса, а он никогда не врет. Проверяйте. Что за пакет у класса написан, что за структура папок проекта, области видимости и т.п.